# Unexpected error using "stdin" in bedtools intersect as a piped command

Tags: bedtools

From the bedtools intersect man (for version 2.30.0):

```
-a BAM/BED/GFF/VCF file “A”. Each feature in A is compared to B in search of overlaps. 
   Use “stdin” if passing A with a UNIX pipe.
```

The stdin part, however, does not apply to version 2.27.1. The help on this version gives no advice for piping.

```
bam mem ref fq1.fastq fq2.fastq | samtools view -b | bedtools intersect -a stdin -b blacklist.bed -v > align_black.sam
Error: unable to open file or unable to determine types for file stdin

- Please ensure that your file is TAB delimited (e.g., cat -t FILE).
- Also ensure that your file has integer chromosome coordinates in the
  expected columns (e.g., cols 2 and 3 for BED).
```

I also tried:

```
(map to bam) | bedtools intersect -a "stdin" -b blacklist.bed -v > align_black.sam
(map to bam) | bedtools intersect -a -b blacklist.bed -v > align_black.sam
(map to bam) | bedtools intersect -b blacklist.bed -v > align_black.sam
```

But these don't work either, either for the same or a different reason. Here is a site that tells me to use the above syntax: https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/example-usage.html

What is the solution to this if I want to pipe everything together for my users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With v2.27.1 (or any version I ever used) instead of `stdin` use `-`

```
(...) | bedtools intersect -a - -b blacklist.bed -v > out.bam
```

Be aware that the output of this is a BAM, not SAM file. It would be easier though to simply make a list of regions you want to keep, e.g. the complement of the backlist file with the entire genome (bedtools complement), and then use `samtools view -L` option to only keep overlapping reads. That saves you the run through `bedtools`.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why this isn't in the docs. I had my own workaround before you commented, but I'll accept this as the answer. Is there a reason you suggest not using bedtools?

Comment: @Jeff As samtools can do the same and you anyway run it you save one additional tool/pipe/core. That is the only reason. Not sure how the performance compares.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to skip conversion to BAM and pipe between tools, which performs the same set operations:

```
$ bam mem ref fq1.fastq fq2.fastq | sam2bed - | bedops -e 1 - blacklist.bed > blacklisted_reads.bed
```

With this toolkit, the hyphen (`-`) follows a Unix convention of serving as a placeholder for stdin.

Answer (score 1):

While I have chosen ATpoint as the official answer, another possible syntax to use is

```
bedtools intersect -a stdin -b blacklist.bed -v < `(map to bam)` > align_black.bam
```

The main issue with this syntax is that it obfuscates the direction of flow for the pipeline, piping step 2 after step 1 is better in the official answer.